# Adding a slideshow dynamically by proving json data

Tags: php

Actually i have a json file(images.json)

```
 {
       "images":  [
        {"title": "Image One", "url": "image1.jpg", "rating": "3.5"},
        {"title": "Image Two", "url": "image2.jpg", "rating": "1"},
        {"title": "Image Three", "url": "image3.jpg", "rating": "5"}
      ]
    }
```

I need to create a slideshow by using this json data
And i have tried this by searching your site but i couldn't get the result expected

```
    <html>
    <body>
         <div class="main">
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div> 
    </body>
    </html>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
         $(function(){

         var json = {
         "slider":[{
         "img"    : "image1.jpg",
        "title"  : "Beady little eyes",
        "expert" : "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
        },
        {
        "img"    : "image2.jpg",
        "title"  : "Beady little eyes",
        "expert" : "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
        }
       ]};

// if you are getting json like above response in ajax
// then simply retrive slider and iterate over it
      var mhtml = '<ul>';
      $.each(json.slider, function(key, val){
      mhtml += '<li><div class="bannerImg"><img src="'+val.img+'" /></div>';
      mhtml += '<h1 class="title">'+val.title+'</h1>';
      mhtml += '<p class="expert">'+val.expert+'</p>';
      mhtml += '</li>';
      });
     mhtml += '</ul>';
     $('#slideshow').append($(mhtml));// append DOM only one time.
     })});
</script>
```

Can you please mention any style sheets or scripting files need to be imported

Comment: How are u displaying the images?You are just appending the texts not the tags to display them.

Answer (score 0):

there were no element with id `slideshow` and jquery library was missing. hope it will work now. the is below -

```
<html>
<body>
     <div class="main">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div id="slideshow" class="content"></div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $(function(){

     var json = {
         "slider":[{
         "img"    : "image1.jpg",
         "title"  : "Beady little eyes",
         "expert" : "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
       },
       {
         "img"    : "image2.jpg",
         "title"  : "Beady little eyes",
         "expert" : "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
       }]
    };

  // if you are getting json like above response in ajax
  // then simply retrive slider and iterate over it
  var mhtml = '<ul>';
  $.each(json.slider, function(key, val) {
      mhtml += '<li><div class="bannerImg"><img src="'+val.img+'" /></div>';
      mhtml += '<h1 class="title">'+val.title+'</h1>';
      mhtml += '<p class="expert">'+val.expert+'</p>';
      mhtml += '</li>';
  });
  mhtml += '</ul>';console.log(mhtml);
  $('#slideshow').append($(mhtml));// append DOM only one time.
 })
});
 </script>
```

Comment: It's displaying images how to display it as slideshow as i'm new to the concept can you help  me need any css or script files to be imported?

Comment: I have tried some plugins and one of them i have tried is http://reallysimpleworks.com/slideshow/      And the code i have written is          <body>
     <div class="main">
    <div class="title"></div>
    
    <div id="slideshow"  class="rs-slideshow">
        <div class="slide-container">
            <img src="Slide/images/morzine-2011-c.png" alt="The first image in a slideshow demo." title="This is the first slide" />
            <span class="slide-caption">This is the first slide</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
</body>

Comment: I'm having problem with output it's just displaying the image in slide which is written in <div> tag but not displaying images that are dynamically added

Comment: You cant expect all the code here. try to figure it out the problem on ur own.